# Mi programa se cicla cuando introduzco caracteres, ¿necesto saber que hacer para que acepte solo numeros enteros?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int mes;

int main()
{
    do
    {
        printf("\n\n Introduce un numero del 1 al 12 correspondiente al mes de tu eleccion: ");
            scanf( "%d", &mes );            
               switch (mes)
                {
                case  1 : printf( "\n\n Enero.");
                        break;
                case  2 : printf( "\n\n Febrero.");
                        break;
                case  3 : printf( "\n\n Marzo.");
                        break;
                case  4 : printf( "\n\n Abril.");
                        break;
                case  5 : printf( "\n\n Mayo.");
                        break;
                case  6 : printf( "\n\n Junio.");
                        break;
                case  7 : printf( "\n\n Julio.");
                        break;
                case  8 : printf( "\n\n Agosto.");
                        break;
                case  9 : printf( "\n\n Septiembre.");
                        break;
                case  10 : printf( "\n\n Octubre.");
                        break;
                case  11 : printf( "\n\n Noviembre.");
                        break;
                case  12 : printf( "\n\n Diciembre.");
                        break;
                break;  
                default: printf( "\n\n ERROR: Ingresaste una opcion no existente." );
                break;
                }
    } while (mes !=12 &&);      
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenias errores de sintaxis el `switch` y error de lógica en las condiciones del `do while`.Mas allá de eso agregué código para validar que solo se ingresen números. Te dejo el código corregido. Saludos!

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int mes;

int main()
{
    do
    {
        printf("\n\n Introduce un numero del 1 al 12 correspondiente al mes de tu eleccion: ");
            char *p, s[100];
            while (fgets(s, sizeof(s), stdin)) {
                    mes = strtol(s, &p, 10);
                    if (p == s || *p != '\n') {
                        printf("Solo debe ingresar numeros. Por favor, ingrese nuevamente una opcion: ");
                    } else break;
                }

               switch (mes)
                {
                case  1 : printf( "\n\n Enero.");
                        break;
                case  2 : printf( "\n\n Febrero.");
                        break;
                case  3 : printf( "\n\n Marzo.");
                        break;
                case  4 : printf( "\n\n Abril.");
                        break;
                case  5 : printf( "\n\n Mayo.");
                        break;
                case  6 : printf( "\n\n Junio.");
                        break;
                case  7 : printf( "\n\n Julio.");
                        break;
                case  8 : printf( "\n\n Agosto.");
                        break;
                case  9 : printf( "\n\n Septiembre.");
                        break;
                case  10 : printf( "\n\n Octubre.");
                        break;
                case  11 : printf( "\n\n Noviembre.");
                        break;
                case  12 : printf( "\n\n Diciembre.");
                        break;

                default: printf( "\n\n ERROR: Ingresaste una opcion no existente." );
                break;
                }
    } while (mes < 1 || mes > 12 );   
return 0;
}
```